# How to display content to specific IPs

Tags: php, html, ip-address

I'm trying to display a div to a specific IP address. How would I go about doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: please provide more information about your application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most simple would be this:

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == "127.0.0.1")
{
    echo "<div>Nothing beats home</div>";
}    

?>
```

Beware that if the server is behind a NAT the $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] will be that of the router if your using port forwarding.

Answer (score 7):

```
if ( $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '192.168.1.114' )
    // show the div
```

Comment: This will return the server's IP, not the user's. `REMOTE_ADDR` is what you're looking for

Answer (score 1):

```
if (isset($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"])){$ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];}
else if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"])){$ip = $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];}
else if ( isset($_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"])){$ip = $_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"];}

if($ip == 'xxx.xxx.xxx'){echo '<div>special content</div>';}
```